# Bootstrap Confirmation onConfirm not firing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a simple confirmation dialog that fires an event when confirmed. Here is the event handler:

```
$('.application-delete-button').on('confirmed.bs.confirmation', function() {
    alert('Confirmed! App ID: '+$(this).attr('data-id')+' | New Status: '+$(this).attr('data-status'));
});
```

And here is the button itself:

```
<button class="application-delete-button" data-toggle="confirmation" data-id="6" data-status="0"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
```

At first I thought it might be because of the class selector and the buttons not having specific IDs, but the same problem arises even when applying unique IDs to the buttons. The problem is that nothing happens when the dialog is confirmed. No errors and the event is not triggered.

I also tried

```
.on('confirm')
```

To no avail. I've also tried setting the data-on-confirm attribute to a static function, but that just produces an 'options.onConfirm is not a function' error.

What am I doing wrong here? I'd appreciate any guidance.

By the way, this is the version I'm using:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-confirmation/1.0.5/bootstrap-confirmation.js
```

Comment: what error you are getting in browser console?

Comment: Please check `bootstrap-confirmation` js included im html or not.

Comment: I'm not getting an error unless I try to use the data-on-confirm attribute, which produces a '$(...).onConfirm is not a function' error. And also yes, the javascript is included. The dialog is coming up fine, it's just that the confirmation event is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the onConfirm function within bootstrap confirm, for example:

```
$('.application-delete-button').confirmation({
    onConfirm: function(event) {alert('Confirmed! App ID: '+$(this).attr('data-id')+' | New Status: '+$(this).attr('data-status')); }
```

Comment: Hm, I changed the handler to the following: `$('.application-delete-button').onConfirm(function() {
        alert('Confirmed! App ID: '+$(this).attr('data-id')+' | New Status: '+$(this).attr('data-status'));
    });` however I'm still getting a $(...).onConfirm is not a function error.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Any time I try to use a variation of 'onConfirm', I get the error. Without it, the dialog shows fine but the event doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out the solution to the issue I was having. In short, what I wanted was for the dialog confirmation to trigger an event. So this is what I did:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("[data-toggle=confirmation]").confirmation({container:"body",btnOkClass:"btn btn-sm btn-success",btnCancelClass:"btn btn-sm btn-danger",onConfirm:function(event, element) { element.trigger('confirm'); }});
}
```

And then for the event handler:

```
$('.application-delete-button').on('confirm', function() {
    alert('Confirmed! App ID: '+$(this).attr('data-id')+' | New Status: '+$(this).attr('data-status'));
});
```

The key was adding this bit to the confirmation init:

```
onConfirm:function(event, element) { element.trigger('confirm'); }
```

For some reason the default event of 'confirmed.bs.confirmation' does not actually fire properly, so you have to manually fire your own event.